# mongoimport csv ignore commented lines

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I am doing mongoimport with csv type and couldn't find an option to ignore commented lines. My csv has commented lines that are marked with "#" as the starting character. Basically, I am invoking MongoDB through a node.js app. No way to ignore these? Could someone suggest if there is an option?

Comment: could anyone help me with a way to ignore commented lines while doing mongoimport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CSV (Comma Separated Values)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) format is intentionally simple and does not have support for comments.  You'll have to pre-filter your commented lines before passing through to `mongoimport`.

`mongoimport` is intended to be used from a command-line, but you've mentioned you are talking to MongoDB from a Node.js app.

Rather than invoking `mongoimport`, I would recommend using a [node.js csv module](https://nodejsmodules.org/tags/csv).  You can then easily do your own line-based filtering for comments or other format deviations, and insert using the [MongoDB driver](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/) directly.

Comment: thanks for confirming that mongoimport-csv doesn't support commented code filtering;
On node.js csv module, I initially tried using this but found serious performance issues as I had to import around 75000 rows from the csv; i used the node-mongo-native to load; then switched to mongoimport through node.js;

Comment: There are a few different [node.js CSV modules](https://nodejsmodules.org/tags/csv). A quick search didn't turn up any obvious benchmarks/comparisons, but [Fast-csv](http://c2fo.github.com/fast-csv/) looks interesting .. trades off some features like multi-line rows for speed.

Comment: thanks Stennie, I shall try Fast-csv, next. Meanwhile, I moved my nodejs codebase and mongodb server env (both in the same server); But, the results are not so pleasing as below. Is this an issue with network latency that cannot be addressed? Config: RAM-8GB; csvdata-75000 rows =9.12MB; Server-Windows server 2008;
mongodb connection accepted time:-
browser client localhost - 75000 rows - instantaneous
browser client remote    - 15 rows - instantaneous
browser client remote    - 10000 rows - 6 sec
browser client remote    - 20000 rows - 18 sec
browser client remote    - 75000 rows - 75 sec